# Python : convert string to datetime with optional milliseconds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, format, string-to-datetime

I'm using the following code to convert strings in a dataframe column to datetime and add 60 days for each row.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_string'], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ") + timedelta(days=60)
```

Due to the fact that I load data from an external API and write it in `df['datetime_string']`, I receive different data like:
`"2023-11-24T09:34:18Z"`
`"2023-11-24T09:35:19.130122Z"` so sometimes I don't have the milliseconds part in the string.

Which leads to a `ValueError: time data "2023-11-24T09:34:18Z" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"`

I want to fill the missing milliseconds part with .000000 and always have the `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ` format.

What is the best way to do this especially when dealing with huge data ?

Comment: do not provide a `format` at all (your input is pretty standard) - or with pandas v2, use `format="ISO8601"`.

Comment: btw. avoid a literal `Z` in format strings. use `%z` to parse Z in the input. if you want naive datetime as result, explicitly remove the time zone by `.dt.tz_localize(None)`.

Comment: Thank you @FObersteiner for your comment but when I do not provide a `format` or use `format="ISO8601"` when converting `"2023-11-24T09:35:19.130122Z"` (for example) I have `2023-11-24 09:35:19.130122+00:00` which is not at all the disered format..

Comment: There seems to be a misconception here - if you parse a string [to a datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) object, that datetime object does not have a *format*, it's a data structure. Only datetime in a string has a "format". So if your input string does not specify microseconds, that doesn't mean they won't be "in" the resulting datetime - it will just be zero.

Comment: Besides, the `+00:00` is for UTC, that's what the Z stands for. Have a look at [naive vs. aware datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects).

Answer (score 0):

First add a millisecond to the datetime, then convert again with the required format:

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_string'])+ timedelta(milliseconds=0, days=60), format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but this is still giving the same Err `ValueError: time data "2023-11-24T09:34:18Z" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"`

Comment: What do you get when you run only: `pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_string'])+ timedelta(milliseconds=0, days=60)` ?

Comment: The same error. The problem is with `pd.to_datetime` formatting

Comment: You can't get this error when you run only this: 
`pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_string'])+ timedelta(milliseconds=0, days=60)`
there is no formatting here..

My suggestion was to separate your logic into two lines: 
the first one converts the string to datetime without formatting and add millisecond and 60 days to the result:
`datetime_with_millisecond = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_string'])+ timedelta(milliseconds=0, days=60)`
the second one convert the result into datetime with your required format :
`result = pd.to_datetime(datetime_with_millisecond, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")`

Answer (score 0):

The clean way to parse mixed ISO8601 compatible formats is to use pandas v2's `format="ISO8601"` keyword argument:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"datetime_string": ["2023-11-24T09:34:18Z", "2023-11-24T09:35:19.130122Z"]})

df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime_string"], format="ISO8601")

# gives
df
               datetime_string                         datetime
0         2023-11-24T09:34:18Z        2023-11-24 09:34:18+00:00
1  2023-11-24T09:35:19.130122Z 2023-11-24 09:35:19.130122+00:00

df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------           --------------  -----
 0   datetime_string  2 non-null      object
 1   datetime         2 non-null      datetime64[ns, UTC]
dtypes: datetime64[ns, UTC](1), object(1)
memory usage: 164.0+ bytes
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `np.where` and explicitly check for the milliseconds component:

```py
np.where(df['datetime_string'].str.contains(r'\.\d+Z$', regex=True),
         pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_string'], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"),
         pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_string'], format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"))
    + timedelta(days=60)
```